# How to make a discord bot send an Invite?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am making a discord bot that can kick and ban members, and I would like to know how can I make the bot send invites to users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's possible to create invites with the method `GuildChannel.createInvite()`.

```
message.channel.createInvite({ unique: true, temporary: false }).then(invite => {
  console.log(invite.code);
});
```

With that invite code, you could combine it with `https://discord.gg/` to make a functional link, which you can then send to users.'

`unique` makes sure the invite is different from all others in the server, and `temporary` is 'whether members that joined via the invite should be automatically kicked after 24 hours if they have not yet received a role'.
You can read more about this method and its options [at the docs.](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=createInvite)